# Wktmtopdf is not rendering flexbox properly

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert my HTML page to PDF using wkhtmltopdf. The CSS is working completely fine when I'm rendering in the browser. It is using flex-box. I know flex-box doesn't work as expected and we have to use `webkit` for that purpose.

Result of PDF conversion (Faulty CSS)
[image: Result of PDF conversion]

Actual HTML page with CSS working fine.
[image: Actual HTML page with CSS working fine.]

CSS for the div section

```css
display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Can anyone help with Flexbox mystery?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="flexing-container">
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
    <span class="flexing-items">12345</span>
</div>

//css
.flexing-container{
width: 300px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
position: static;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexing-items{
margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Hope that will help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).